# NodeJs Lambda function - Variable value not properly getting showing after placing

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

There is a Lambda code where I am trying to isert a varibale to a string.

```
var arg1 = "database1";
var params = {
  Message: "[ { \"type\": \"section\", \"text\": { \"type\": \"mrkdwn\", \"text\": \"Hourly snapshot has been created for : "+arg1+" \" } }, { \"type\": \"divider\" } ]";
}
console.log('PARAMS.msgbody : ' + params.Message)
```

So that the output of printing this variable should look like this

```
LATEST
2022-01-23T21:16:40.735Z    00e4c398-4038-473c-83fa-1981d8d311b3    INFO    PARAMS.msgbody : [ { "type": "section", "text": { "type": "mrkdwn", "text": "Hourly snapshot has been created for : database1 " } }, { "type": "divider" } ]
```

But instead of this I am getting this where the variable value is replaced but with extra double qoutes. How can I solve this ?

```
LATEST
2022-01-23T21:16:40.735Z    00e4c398-4038-473c-83fa-1981d8d311b3    INFO    PARAMS.msgbody : [ { "type": "section", "text": { "type": "mrkdwn", "text": "Hourly snapshot has been created for : "database1" " } }, { "type": "divider" } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it simple by [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
var params = {
  Message: `[ { "type": "section", "text": { "type": "mrkdwn", "text": "Hourly snapshot has been created for : ${arg1} " } }, { "type": "divider" } ]`,
}
```

Or just convert a JSON object to a string:

```
var params = {
  Message: JSON.stringify([
    {
      type: "section",
      text: {
        type: "mrkdwn",
        text: "Hourly snapshot has been created for : " + arg1,
      }
    },
    {
      type: "divider",
    },
  ]),
}
```